# A variable assigned to all rows of a column, enters a loop with only the value of the last row

Tags: python, io, lines

**EDIT**

In this code `analysis.py` I have written, the variable `entropy` is a column of data.

When I pass all the rows to a loop, only the last value is considered:

To run this code, it is only necessary 2 files in the folder:

`pressure_enthalpy_all_points.dat`:

```
# pressure enthalpy
2         3
5         4
3.5       2
```

`entropies_parsed.dat`:

```
# entropies
0.5        
0.2        
0.47
```

**Code**  `analysis.py` included the nested loop from comments:

```
import numpy as np



pressure_gibbs = open('pressure_gibbs_all_points.dat', 'w') 

pressure_gibbs.write('#pressure    gibbs\n')

## FUNCTION:

def G(H,S):
# G = H - TS 
# Then:
  gibbs = H - 298.15 * S/4.0
  return gibbs



with open('entropies_parsed.dat') as entropies_parsed, open('pressure_enthalpy_all_points.dat') as enthalpy_pressure:  # open the file
  entropies_parsed.next() # skip the first line
  enthalpy_pressure.next()

  for line in entropies_parsed: # iterate over the remaining lines
      entropy = float(line)

      for line in enthalpy_pressure:
        pressure, enthalpy = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
        gibbs = G(enthalpy, entropy)

        pressure_gibbs.write('{}\t{}\n'.format (pressure, gibbs))

pressure_gibbs.close()
```

**This gives a file**, `pressure_gibbs_all_points.dat`:

```
#pressure    gibbs
2.0     -34.26875
5.0     -33.26875
3.5     -35.26875
```

That `gibbs = -34.26875` is the result of making `3 -298.15 * 0.5 / 4.0` , where:
`3 = pressure` (1st row of `pressure_enthalpy_all_points.dat` file)
 and 
`0.5 = entropy` (1st row `entropies_parsed.dat`)

Obviously this is wrong.... All the `gibbs` rows have the same value because the 2nd and 3rd rows of `pressure_gibbs_all_points.dat` have been generated from the 1st row of `pressure_enthalpy_all_points.dat` and the 1st row of `entropies_parsed.dat` .

I can't see where is the problem here, the `n`th row of  `gibbs` should be generated from the `n`th rows of `pressure_gibbs_all_points.dat` and `pressure_enthalpy_all_points.dat`

Comment: can you print your value for line in enthalpy_pressure?  Maybe not what you think?  also print after next line both variables

Comment: @joel goldstick Not sure what do you mean by "can you print your value for line in enthalpy_pressure? "  and by "also print after next line both variables". I have copied the exact code in the post and the exact `.dat` files someone would need to reproduce the problem

Comment: I was wondering if debugging that inner loop might show something that you didn't expect with the variables you are collecting

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your looping .First loop will get execute completely and then the entropy variable will hold the final value in the file . So when you enter the second loop and print it , you get to see only the final entry of entropy.
I guess you meant to write a nested loop there!

Comment: Every time you try to indent `for line in enthalpy_pressure:` it gives the classical unindent error

Comment: can you show updated code with complete traceback. I'm not sure what classical unindent error means -- but could you have mixed spaces and tabs?

Comment: @joelgoldstick Updated

Comment: That line needs to be lined up with the line above it (indent 2 more spaces

Comment: @joelgoldstick Thanks, but Updated 2 gives that error- I don't understand why, if `enthalpy_pressure.next()` declaration is outside all loops

Comment: That error means that enthalpy_pressure doesn't have any more items.  Not sure why. But you also open it to write at the top of your code.  Maybe its locked?

Comment: @joelgoldstick Yes, I have fixed that, see the EDITed question now